# AngularJs long scrolling to different views...possible?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I've decided to partly modify my website to allow long scrolling.

But I can't get my head around this concept...So I'll try to explain it as clearly as I can.  Currently my website has a nav bar,  you click one button...angular changes the view from partials/differentview.html etc.  This works.

But I would like it to do this:  When the user scrolls down...it goes to section 2...scroll down again....section 3 etc.  I would like the different sections to represent different pages.

Hopefully this image will help:[image]

The red box represents the PC monitor view.  Is it possible when the user selects section 3 on Nav bar...the screen scrolls down to section 3 without it changing the view?

Do I need to have section1.html, section2.html, section3.html separately in partials or is it possible to have both sections in one html file?

I'm not sure if this is the angular way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create separate html files. You can use `ngSwitch` directive to navigate through different sections. More more info, see the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).